# Alternative way to use $(element).on('change', () => {})

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have a problem I hope you can help me:

I'm using bootstrap selectpicker which use the onchange event of the element (I think)

I need to add another event handler to the select element, I did and both works right, the problem is that with every certain changes in my page the table that I use reloads all the data and when that happens the table will add that event handler **again** to the select element and will do the same thing twice (or more)

So, before assignment of the event I tried to use

```
$('.selectpicker.call').off('change')
```

But when I do that I remove the event handler of the bootstrap selectpicker too

Do you guys know any other trick that I could use instead of jquery onchange?

Thank you!

Comment: Let me clarify - your code is calling some version of `$(element).on('change', () => {})` and you want to remove just the handlers added by you, correct?

Comment: Yeah, right. That's what I want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [namespaces for the events](https://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) this way you can distinguish just the events you've added as opposed to other events.

Let's take a very simple example - there is a button with some default functionality (Click me) and we can add more event handlers to it. We also want to clear the event handlers but not break the default functionality:

```js
//assume some code outside our control
$("#clickme").on("click", () => console.log("Default functionality"));


//our code
$("#set_message").on("click", () =>{
  const message = $("#message").val();
  $("#clickme").on("click", () => console.log(message));
});
$("#clear_message").on("click", () =>{
  $("#clickme").off("click");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input id="message" value="add your message here">
  <button id="set_message">Set message</button>
  <button id="clear_message">Clear message</button>
</div>

<div>
  <button id="clickme">Click me</button>
</div>
```

This doesn't work because the "Clear message" button removes *all* event handlers - those added by others or not.

Instead, we can namespace events. For example `click.myEvent` is still a click event but within the `myEvent` namespace. If we remove `click.myEvent` it only removes events from that namespace leaving anything else intact. So "Clear message" now only clears our event handlers:

```js
//assume some code outside our control
$("#clickme").on("click", () => console.log("Default functionality"));


//our code
$("#set_message").on("click.myEvent", () =>{
  const message = $("#message").val();
  $("#clickme").on("click.myEvent", () => console.log(message));
});
$("#clear_message").on("click.myEvent", () =>{
  $("#clickme").off("click.myEvent");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input id="message" value="add your message here">
  <button id="set_message">Set message</button>
  <button id="clear_message">Clear message</button>
</div>

<div>
  <button id="clickme">Click me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @AngelQuesada during a global pandemic? OK but just don't infect me, please :P

Answer (score 1):

Change this `$('.selectpicker.call').on('change',function(){....})` to `$('body').on('change'','.selectpicker.call',function(){....})` and load this function only once.

What this does is it assigns the function to `body` and triggers whenever a `change` event is triggered on `.selectpicker.call` element. So even if your data keeps changing, this function doesn't.

Comment: Not working :( The problem is that when the table reloads that function is assigned again to the element so it makes the same thing more than one time

Comment: @AngelQuesada what is the table data? does the table data reload assigns a function automatically? Also, check out VLAZ 's answer. It should work

Comment: Yeah it does, it has the "drawCallBack" method and everytime it reload the data it assigns the the event again because all element are created from 0